# What type of crimping pliers do I need for these connectors

Tags: lights, wiring, tools, bumper, fog

I have to run some cables in the bumper and I want to use waterproof connectors housing. The problem is that I don't have any crimping pliers and I don't know what type should I buy for this type of pins/connectors. Thank you.
[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: Those are "AMP Superseal" connectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe crimping pliers for  weather pack, metri-pack, or molex connectors will work.  IWISS makes a tool just for those types of connectors.  Alternatively, Paladin makes a crimping tool with die sets for those and other types of connectors.

Comment: I've found  2 pliers. One of them is only for molex ( https://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-Compression-Ratcheting-0-1-1-0mm2-Wire-electrode/dp/B01A0SAQ3W/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1514964829&sr=8-2&keywords=IWISS ), described as 28-18AWG. The other one is with changeable die sets( https://www.amazon.co.uk/Non-insulated-Insulated-End-sleeves-Terminals-Changeable/dp/B01A9QSTX4/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1514964829&sr=8-3&keywords=IWISS ) and the one similar to the molex is described as 16-10AWG. Do you think that the second one will do the work, because I might also need the other die sets.

Comment: I assume those would work.  I have used the Paladin 1300 series frame  and 2033 die set.  I have also used the IWISS IWS-1424B crimping tool.  I have used the Paladin frame and die sets in an industrial environment.  They are quality tools.  The IWISS tool is economical, but I don't think it would hold up as well.

Comment: Paladin 1300 series frame:  https://www.amazon.co.uk/1300-CRIMP-HAND-PALADIN-TOOLS/dp/B01186PUC2/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1514984412&sr=8-15&keywords=paladin+13004

Comment: Paladin 2033 die set:  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Paladin-Tools-PA2033-1300-Interchangeable/dp/B000JJJ6B6/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1514984629&sr=8-1&keywords=paladin+1300+2033

Comment: IWISS IWS-1424B:  https://www.amazon.co.uk/IWS-1424B-Crimping-Termianls-Metri-Pack-Connectors/dp/B071KFLY43/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1514984750&sr=8-1&keywords=IWISS+Weather+pack+Crimper+Tools+for+Crimping+Delphi+Packard+Weather+pack+Terminals+or+Metri-Pack+Connectors

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I cant spend that amount of money for the paladin tools, so I will go for the IWISS one. Let's hope that it will do the job.

Comment: You're welcome!  Best of luck with your project :-)